# Pywinauto - Alternatives for Double click

Tags: python, pywinauto

Currently i'm using Pywinauto along with Behave to test a desktop application and i have encountered a road bump.
at one point in my automation i need to use double click, currently i have it working as this:

```
@step("User selects {row} in Multi payment window")
def step_impl(context, row):
    """
    :param row: that we are going to fill.
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    tries = 5
    for i in range(tries):
        try:
            context.popup[str(row)].click_input(button='left', double=True)
        except:
            if i < tries - 1:  # i is zero indexed
                continue
        else:
            break
```

It works perfectly! but if i'm not present or the machine is open this will cause issues because i'm using *click_input()* so i have tried using *click(double=True)* but it doesn't seems to be able to click on it, is there anything i could do to get around this?

This is the result of running print_control_identifiers(), The items i'm trying to double click is Row 0 and Row 1, they are custom items.

[image: print_control_identifiers]

Comment: were you able to solve the riddle?

Comment: Not as of right now, I have been pulled around to Work on a different project, I haven't touched that code in a while.

Answer (score 1):

*This is very low-level and tries to emulate winapi double click. May be there are more idiomatic ways to do that.*

See code [here](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/controls/hwndwrapper.py#L1704) and explanation of the actual sequence of events [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-lbuttondblclk):

> Double-clicking the left mouse button actually generates a sequence of four messages: WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, and WM_LBUTTONUP.

I extract window handle using `app.windows()[0].handle` then create `HwndWrapper` out of it `HwndWrapper(handle)` and then call `HwndWrapper.double_click`:

```
from pywinauto import Application
from pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper import HwndWrapper

app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'MFCApplication1.exe')
HwndWrapper(app.windows()[0].handle).double_click()
app.kill()
```

the wrapper then reproduces the sequence.

This works even if your window is not visible.

Comment: I tried it an got this error `KeyError: <bound method BaseWrapper.class_name of <uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Row 0', Custom, 3527539>>` 
this is how i implemented your answer:
`HwndWrapper(context.popup[f'{str(row)}']).double_click()`

Comment: Try add `.handle`: `HwndWrapper(context.popup[f'{str(row)}'].handle).double_click()`

Comment: Trying that Returns     class_name = element.class_name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_name'

Comment: What is the value and type of `context.popup[f'{str(row)}']`?

Comment: This is the result of Running Type on it <class 'pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification'>